# multiple two column values with grouping by a column

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I've two tables tblOrder and tblOrderDetails. I want to get order no, total price per order (Quantity*UnitCost) and OrderDate as given below.

| Order No | Total | OrderDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ORD 1 | 3000 | 01/01/2021 |
| ORD 2 | 2750 | 01/03/2021 |

**What I've tried is giving me quantity is not a part of aggregate function.**

SELECT tblOrder.OrderNo, tblOrderDetails.UnitCost*tblOrderDetails.Quantity AS Total, OrderDate
FROM tblOrderDetails INNER JOIN tblOrder ON tblOrderDetails.OrderId = tblOrder .OrderId
GROUP BY tblOrder.OrderNo;

Table structures and data

Table tblOrder:

| OrderId | OrderNo | OrderDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ORD 1 | 01/01/2021 |
| 2 | ORD 2 | 01/03/2021 |

Table tblOrderDetails:

| OrderDetailId | Quantity | UnitCost | OrderId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 30 | 1 |
| 2 | 50 | 40 | 2 |
| 2 | 10 | 15 | 2 |
| 2 | 20 | 30 | 2 |

Comment: @JonasMetzler single order can contain multiple order details. I have updated the question please check

Comment: Jonas Metzler version will work but if you want to retrieve more fields from tblOrder, use DannySlor version. Or build a report and use its Sorting & Grouping feature with aggregate calcs in textbox. This allows display of detail records as well as summary data.

Answer (score 1):

```
select   o.OrderNo
        ,od.total
        ,o.OrderDate
from
(
select   OrderId
        ,sum(Quantity*UnitCost) as total
from     tblOrderDetails 
group by OrderId
) od join tblOrder o on o.OrderId = od.OrderId
```

| OrderNo | total | OrderDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ORD 1 | 3000 | 2021-01-01 |
| ORD 2 | 2750 | 2021-01-03 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KsNiUuib)

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements are not 100% clear, but maybe, you can just do this, without any subquery:

```
SELECT tblOrder.OrderNo, 
SUM(tblOrderDetails.UnitCost*tblOrderDetails.Quantity) AS Total, 
OrderDate 
FROM tblOrderDetails 
INNER JOIN tblOrder ON tblOrderDetails.OrderId = tblOrder.OrderId 
GROUP BY tblOrder.OrderNo,OrderDate;
```

To see the difference to Danny's answer - which might also be fine - have a look here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/CHM1FUsa)

Comment: it's better to join tables as late as possible in the process.